# Was the Akshay Patra ever used before Mahabharat?

Tags: rishi, devi-bhagavata-purana, saptarshi, gayatri

**[Chapter 9 of Book 12 of the Devi Bhagvat Puran](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk12ch09.htm)** mentions the following benediction by Devi Gayatri to Rishi Gautam:

> Thus praised and worshipped, the World-Mother appeared and gave to the Risi **one vessel full to the brim by which every one can he fed and nourished.** The Mother told the Muni :-- **“This full vessel, given by me to you will yield whatever you wish.”** Thus saying, the Devî Gâyatrî, Higher than the Highest, vanished.
>
> **Then, according to the wish of the Muni, came out from that cup, mountains of cooked rice, various curries and sweetmeats, lots of grass and fodder,** silken clothings, various ornaments and various articles and vessels for sacrificial purposes. In fact whatever the Muni Gautama wished, that came out of the brimful cup, given by the Devî Gâyatrî. Then the Muni Gautama called the other Munis that came there and gave them wealth, grains, clothing, ornament, and the sacrificial ladles and spoons and cows and buffaloes for the sacrificial purposes.

The vessel thus serves a smilar purpose as the **Akshay Patra** given to the Pandavs by Surya but surpasses it by providing even other items of need to Rishi Gautam. **I want to know if it was the same vessel or a different one and if different is it mentioned with its name in any other scripture?**

Comment: In Ramayana, a feasts given by Sage Vasistha and Sage Bharadwaja  were narrated.  Of course, they could do it with with DIVINE will/power, though no vessel was mentioned.@Dr. Vineet Aggarwal

Comment: @srimannarayanakv yeah Brahmarishi Vasishtha could do it through Kamdhenu that feast was the basis of the envy that got generated in Vishwamitra's mind.